# MongoDB track location using Geolocation API

Tags: python, database, mongodb, api, geolocation

I am new database management systems.I want to track location with Geolocation API and I want to store locations that collected in MongoDB instanly. I want to explain with an axample:

For example I start to track a telephone with Geolocation API. When I get the first location coordinates, I want this coordinate to be automatically added to my MongoDB database.

Is it possible to do this example with MongoDB?

Can you give me advice on this matter?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far

Comment: @Tuqay: Actually, I haven't been able to accomplish anything for this purpose yet. I'm new to this and wanted to get your ideas if it is possible to do something like this with MongoDB.